# r.viewshed - Can't find with Grass toolbox

Tags: grass-gis, viewshed

I'm trying to use r.viewshed and have got Grass installed but can't find it anywhere!  under toolbox, I click 'Grass commands (152 geoalgorithms) and have a choice of imagery, raster, vector, etc, etc. under raster I have a long list of tools, but no r.viewshed... anyone know where I'm going wrong?

David.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[r.viewshed](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.viewshed.html) is a GRASS GIS 7 module and an add-on module for GRASS GIS 6.x ([AddOns/GRASS 6](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/AddOns/GRASS_6#r.viewshed)) and the 6.x version is used in the `GRASS commands(159 geoalgorithms`:

#### In QGIS 2.2:

[image]

#### In one of the master's version of QGIS (2.3.x) (with GRASS GIS 7 installed):

[image]

[image]